# Materialized view refresh from view with UDF's in Select

Tags: view, user-defined-functions, oracle12c, materialized-views

We have a Materialized view that is being refreshed from a view but the refresh time is ~1 hour. We need to get that time down substantially for usability.
The view has 26 columns and 25 of those columns come from user-defined functions that encapsulate the companies business logic regarding each column.  The materialized view has 15,000 rows and the refresh is complete.

I had attempted to use PRAGMA UDF to get performance gains and have seen next to negligible improvements (PRAGMA UDF has also be added to any children functions that are used in parent functions as well).
Have also tried unwrapping the business logic from the functions and adding it directly to the SQL and seen no improvement there as well.

Would like some suggestions on alternative solutions/approaches to take to achieve this in a more acceptable refresh time (10-20 min refresh time preferably)

Comment: Short of a generic "trace what's happening to see where the bottleneck is and work on that", it's going to be very hard to suggest anything.  Are there some of the functions that take more time than others?  If so, look at optimizing them.  Are the functions deterministic (I would assume not but you might get lucky)?  If so, you have options for things like caching.  How many rows are you running through these functions?  Are you doing a full refresh?  Could you do an incremental refresh?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the functions are streamlined as much as possible.
Deterministic functions have all been identified.
The number of rows is about 14-15k (tiny).
I am doing a full refresh so I will look at doing an incremental refresh.

Comment: OK, so a full refresh involves ~375,000 function calls.  Are you doing that serially or are you doing a parallel refresh?  375,000 calls in 3600 seconds is about 10 ms per function execution if you're doing a serial refresh.  If that's the case, you could potentially just toss a PARALLEL 4 or PARALLEL 8 on the materialized view and hit your desired time.

Comment: I have never seen/used the parallel parameter before. I will try this tomorrow and update the question with the results. Thanks @Justin Cave

Comment: @JustinCave Can you submit your parallel comment at the answer? It worked perfectly for me. Brought the refresh time down to under 10 minutes.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full refresh involves roughly 375,000 function calls (15,000 row x 25 function calls per row).  375,000 function calls in 3600 seconds is about 10 ms per function execution if you're doing a serial refresh.  There may be ways to optimize the function calls by doing things like ensuring that you're not joining to the same table multiple times in different functions.  If you are doing a serial refresh, the easiest option would likely be to put a `PARALLEL 4` or `PARALLEL 8` on the materialized view so that the refresh can run across multiple sessions in the background.